# Is there a way to stop OS font features like Samsung from changing font?

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, android-fonts, android-security

Was testing my application on a Samsung phone that got font in its settings set to huge, most of my text in grid views and list views where bigger that the title in the app bar, is there a way to prevent this feature from overriding font properties in application?

Comment: The correct solution is for you to fix your UI to handle varying font sizes, so that you do not discriminate against people who have vision issues and need bigger text. You may also need this support to handle translations, as not all strings will be the same length in all languages.

The sloppy solution is to not use `sp` as your text size unit of measure.

Comment: Shifting to 1 item per row where it was 3 items per row to support huge fonts and make it look weird on normal font is not a solution  for me I may refactor all views and add a setting option to set the size of font and items but I don't want the OS to override it.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the font in your `styles.xml` file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">Roboto</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```